# Centrar textos en DomPDF

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
@include('layouts.estilo')
<h1 class="text-center card-title">{{$articulo->titulo}}</h1>
<hr>
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($articulo->foto->ruta())}}"/>
<hr>
<h3 class="text-left">{{$articulo->texto}}</h3>
<hr>
<center>
    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Noticia publicada por {{$articulo->user->nombre()}}</span>
    <br>
    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Esta noticia ha sido publicada el {{$articulo->created_at}}</span>
    @if($articulo->created_at<$articulo->updated_at)
        <br>
        <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Fue actualizada por última vez el {{$articulo->updated_at}}</span>
    @endif
</center>
```

Este código sera usado para imprimir un documento PDF, el cual me da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La mayoria esta bien, pero tal y como he enseñado en la parte subrayada, la etiqueta `center` no esta funcionando.

¿Como centro los textos?

PD: En este formulario importo el fichero `estilo.blade.php`, el cual tiene este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Aparte, me he fijado que el titulo, que es la etiqueta `h1`, si que esta bien centrado. Al intentar sustituir `<center>` por `<div class="text-center card-title">`, fallo de nuevo.
Es más, he comprobado que si se centran los textos al retirar de los `<span>` la parte del `class="badge badge-cat badge-info"`. Cuando usaba una vista normal no daban ningún problema, pero al pasarlo a PDF entra en colisión con el centrado del texto.

Answer (score 0):

Mételo dentro de un `div`.

Ejemplo:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">contenido a centrar</div>
```

Comment: Pues no ha funcionado. He editado mi pregunta.